# Replacing Type attribute text of input outerHTML

Tags: javascript

As `input` type change using `setAttribute` is not supported in IE browsers because of security concerns I am following the below way

```
 div.innerHTML = ele.outerHTML.replace('type=text' , 'type=password');
```

But this is not working if `type="text"` or `type='text'` because it was not replaced.. Is there any regex to match the same in generic way and replace it?

Comment: Try regex: `.replace(/type\=['"]text['"]/i,"type='password'");`

Comment: @Passerby Does it work with type=text case?

Comment: Then try `.replace(/type\=['"]{0,1}text['"]{0,1}/i,"type='password'");`

Comment: @Passerby Can you make it as answer, so that I can accept..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending from comment:

`String.replace` method supports Regex, so you can try:

```
div.innerHTML = ele.outerHTML.replace(/type\=['"]{0,1}text['"]{0,1}/i,"type='password'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex,

```
.replace(/type\=['"]{0,1}text['"]{0,1}/i,"type='password'");
```

@Passerby, Thanks.